# Explanation for these parent and child classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class BaseClass {
    int data = 101;
    public void print() {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
    public void fun() {
        print();
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    int data = 202;
    public void print() {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    } 
}

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass obj = new SubClass();
        obj.print();//call 1
        obj.fun();// call 2
        System.out.print(obj.data);//call2
    } 
}
```

So I have a parent/child relation class and one test class which has call1, call2, call3.

> 1:Regarding call1 , My reasoning was that since **print()** is being overridden by the child class and the function call will print the **data** variable of the correct. This appears to be correct since that is what the correct answer is.
>
> 2: Now regarding call2, since fun is present only in the parent class, so the call will go there and ideally should call the **fun** method of the parent class and output the **data variable**  of the parent class. This is not the correct answer, according to the answer it the  output **data** of the child class.

Can anyone explain to me, what is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). You override the `print()` method in the child so that when the instance of child calls `fun()` it calls it's using the SubClass version of the `print()` method.

As the instance is SubClass it will use the version of the method it has and not its parent.

A good resource on how the JVM resolves its methods can be found [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1997/jw-06-hood.html?page=1)

Comment: +1 Right answer but not completed what about `System.out.print(obj.data);` ?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder That part is straightforward, in case of instance variable there is not overriding and variable refers to the original type of the object.

Comment: Hint on the wording: "original type of the object" is somewhat ... strange. An object has one and only one class definition. After construction that cannot be changed. (Of course, an object can have several types. Its defining class, each super class, and each interface they implement.) What you meant, is the type resolution at compile time. And the compiler only considers declared types. In that case, the declared type of the variable "obj" is BaseClass.

Answer (score 1):

> Now regarding call2, since fun is present only in the parent class, so
>   the call will go there and ideally should call the fun method of the
>   parent class and output the data variable of the parent class. This is
>   not the correct answer, according to the answer it the output data of
>   the child class.

This is not correct. `fun()` of `BaseClass` will call `print()` of `Subclass` because its overriden. **Runtime polymorphism** applies here.

Answer (score 1):

```
   case 1 : obj.fun();
```

You have overridden the `print();` method .
**At runtime java resolves method calling based on the object type.**
So here it searches for method `fun()` first in `SubClass` ,it not found the method there,
since you `SubClass` do not have it(you are not overrridden `fun()` there),and
then it go for `BaseClass` (parent) class and found there the `fun()` method.

**Then there is a method `print()` it has to executes.

Here also it follows the same procedure here,searches first in `SubClass` and found the `print()`

in the `SubClass` itself and executes it**.

So that is whay you are getting the result like that.

```
  case 2 :  System.out.println(obj.data)
```

Here `data` is variable ,
**The compiler only considers the declared type of variables when resolving access to variables(and also when resolving overloading)**
Here declared type is `BaseClass` ,So result is `101`.

If you create object like this

```
   SubClass obj2 = new SubClass(); 
   System.out.println(obj2.data);
```

Then result will be `202`.Since declared type is 'SubClass'.

Comment: Another hint on the wording here: "varibles are always resolved based on the refernce type not based on the Object type". The JLS differs between primitive types and reference types when explaining the type concept. So in that context the wording "reference type" is not really correct. Correct is: The compiler only considers the declared type of variables when resolving access to fields (and also when resolving overloading, btw).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You are right.I have corrected that by editing .Thank you very much for correcting me.